# Input,textfields in different lengths/widths?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

Is there a way to have form elements with different lengths?

In forms.css, i changed the width of title,text fields, but this of course will then apply to all form fields...:/

```
input.text, input.title {width:628px;padding:5px;}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On blueprintcss 1.0.1 you can add the normal span-* classes to inputs as well.

It helps to understand if you can have a look at the source code

https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/master/blueprint/screen.css#L135